# Is it possible to know what is the path of a Class in Ruby using code?

Tags: ruby

I want to know where a class is defined using code, for example:

```
Car.path
=> lib/car.rb
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What would you expect for a class that is defined in two files? What about a class that is defined in no files?

Comment: Fortunately, for what I'm trying to do, those cases are not a problem for me, they will not happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using 2.7 you can call [`Module#const_source_location`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Module.html#method-i-const_source_location):

```
Object.const_source_location(:Set) # => ["C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/set.rb", 70]
```

Comment: I may read announcements of new Ruby methods but it is answers such as yours that tend to commit them to the little grey cells.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I discovered that if I force an exception trying to create an instance of the class with more arguments than allowed I got the stack trace, then I can see the path from it. Not sure if there is a better way.

```
2.6.5 :005 > Set.new 1, 2, 3, 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
        6: from /home/foobar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        5: from /home/foobar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        4: from /home/foobar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        3: from (irb):5
        2: from (irb):5:in `new'
        1: from /home/foobar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/set.rb:93:in `initialize'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1))
```

Comment: This is basically the same as `Set.instance_method(:initialize).source_location` which only tells you the source location of a method definition which (even for `initialize`) might be different than the class definition.

Comment: Well, for now, that's enough to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think it's worth to update your anwser to include this, what do you think?

Comment: This will fail if the method is inherited from a base class.